# The existence of infinite number of primes in a sequence of consecutive squares

Tags: number-theory

I have a sequence of ranges that I am looking for primes in. The sequence is approximately $[n^2, (n+1)^2]$ for specific n. I would like to show that there are an infinite number of primes within these ranges, which is a much weaker statement than Legendre’s conjecture, which would say that every one of those ranges would have a prime.

I asked my analytic number theory professor and he mentioned some theorem stating this would even be true for $N$ and $N+X^{1/6}$ where $N<X \leq 2N$, but I do not remember the precise statement nor can I find a reference.

For clarity, what I am looking to show more specifically is that there is, for all $r>2$ a prime $n_r$ satisfying $(k+1)(r-1)<n_r \leq kr+1$ for some $k>r-2$. This does not require what’s above, and probably has a much simpler explanation, so just solving this would be perfectly fine for me. Either way, I am curious about the answer to the more general problem!

Thanks for the help!

Comment: which $n$ do you care about? obviously, since there are infinitely many primes, there are infinitely many $n$ for which $[n^2,(n+1)^2]$ contains a prime...

Comment: I guess it would be $[kr+r-k-1, kr+1]$ for $k>r-2$. I was hoping there would be something for arbitrary infinite sequences of $n$, but that seems too strong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your main question: there exist arbitrarily large primes congruent to $1$ mod $r - 1$, so you can take a large $k$ such that $(k+1)(r-1)+1$ is prime.

Your professor may have referred to Ingham's result on [prime gaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap): If $c > 0$ such that $\zeta(1/2 + it) = O(t^c)$ then $\pi(x + x^\theta) - \pi(x) \sim x^\theta / \log x$ for any $\theta > (1+4c)/(2+4c)$.

Conjecturally (Lindelöf) we can take $c>0$ arbitrarily small, which would imply that we can take $\theta > 1/2$. ($\theta = 1/2$ would imply Legendre's conjecture.)